# Can't open a luks encrypted partition

Tags: linux, encryption, luks

I have a dead linux system that can't boot now which was lvm encrypted. Now I am on a live linux system trying to recover the data on the /home partition. I have used "cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb3" but it says the partition is already mapped or mounted. I then checked /dev/mapped directory I can see the partition with the device name cr_*****part3. I tried to mount it under /mnt/temp but it says LVM2 type is not recognized?

Comment: I encountered this on a Debian Bullseye system which for some reason had gotten sda and sdb confused (where the one resulting in the error indeed really was busy). Look very closely and double check details such as disk size and manufacturer strings, as not all tools correctly at all times report the device names actually used by the linux kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the luksClose was left in a unstable or  hung state on last attempt.  Try the following: (from the live)

sudo vgchange -an  ;
sudo cryptsetup luksClose /dev/sdb3 (or the /dev/mapper/cr****) I have seen it not like one and take the other randomly.

sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb3 myfailedsystem

sudo mount /dev/mapper/cr***/home /mnt (or wherever)
 then preform whatever recover operations you needed and reverse the process back to the sudo vgchange -an  ; sudo cryptsetup luksClose .....

Comment: Thank you. It's been sometime I gave up already and formatted the partition, since the data there wasn't way too important. Thanks anyway.